# Cast float into a string with a twist

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to convert phone numbers, that are floats of different lengths.
They all have five trailing zeros.

despite the different lengths of the numbers, how do I get rid of the zeros?

```
select 
    RTRIM(STR(c.[From__Number_], 10, 5))AS [To_Number_str]
      FROM database
```

Here is an example:

```
   select 0111.00000 as To__Number_  ,'0111' as needed union 
      select 021123456.00000 as To__Number_ , '021123456' as needed union 
      select 64212121212.00000 as To__Number_ ,'64212121212' as needed
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008, really??  Also, there are many ways to discard the decimal places *(using `CAST(CAST(x AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(32))` or `STR(x, 12, 0)`)*.  But, floating point numbers ***do not*** have leading zeros.  If you store `0111` as a float, you're storing the value "one hundred and eleven" as a binary value, the extra leading zeros you've added are no longer there *(there's no difference between 00111 and 0111 and 111, they're all just 111)*.  See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be725b29eb66afe40fa39cbd66ff98ca

Comment: You right about the zeros, my bad, there aren't any leading ones. THank you for resolving the query! Awesome!!